# ReactiveCocoa - ignore all values

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I am writing a library that has a method returning a RACSignal, but only to be subscribed to Complete and Error, not Next.

I have a RACSignal, that I want to propagate further, but ignoring all values. I get the signal from network call, but I don't want to expose it's values to library user. Inside the method I am doing some things with the data, but for the user I want to expose only Complete and Error events.

`RACStream` has a method `- (instancetype)ignore:(id)value;` which returns new stream with a specific value filtered out - what I want to do is filter out all possible values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `filter` and always return `NO`:

```
[mySignal filter:^(NSString *value) {
    return NO;
}]
```